# Testing React with swagger

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, swagger, jestjs

Can someone tells me how to unit test a React application using Swagger to call my own API ? I'm totally lost...

To run my tests I'm using Jest.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: React is front end (UI). REST API is back end. What exactly do you need to test - the UI or the backend API calls?

Comment: In my opinion unit test should test only your component or just one thing, it should not be relying on anything else.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I'm using Redux to link my front and my back and do the API calls. So I'd like to test my actions and reducers but I don't know how and where to start. Do I need to mock my Swagger API client first ?